# How can I exclude PNG and JPG attachments on Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I have a page where I want to exclude all image attachment on my post from being displayed.

I used this code but it's not working:

```
$attachments = get_posts($args);
if ($attachments) {
    foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
         if (($attachment->post_mime_type!="image/png") || ($attachment->post_mime_type!="image/jpg"))   {  
             echo substr(apply_filters('the_title', $attachment->post_title), 0, 25);
             echo '.zip';
             echo ' - (';
             echo _format_bytes(filesize( get_attached_file( $attachment->ID ) ));
             echo ')';
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Think about your (second) `if` statement for a moment... what you're saying is equivalent to saying that what's valid is anything that's not *both* `image/png` AND `image/jpg`! That's obviously not what you want (nothing will ever be filtered).

Try replacing:

```
if (($attachment->post_mime_type!="image/png") || ($attachment->post_mime_type!="image/jpg"))   {
```

With:

```
if (($attachment->post_mime_type!="image/png") && ($attachment->post_mime_type!="image/jpeg"))   {
```

You're saying that you want it to not be `image/png` AND not `image/jpg`. Remember to be careful with your boolean logic. If ever in doubt, try running various values through it to make sure it's doing what you're assuming it's doing (or even write it down on paper).

Mind you, png and jpg aren't the only types of images out there (don't forget .gif, .bmp, .webp and likely many others modern browsers can display). If you're wanting to exclude *all* image types, this isn't the way to go about it.

Edit: JPEG image's mimetype is actually `image/jpeg` as well, not `image/jpg`

Comment: @URaffJoseph I just double checked and jpeg image's mimetype is actually supposed to be `image/jpeg`, not `image/jpg`.

Comment: ok im DONE... instead of this i used this if (substr($attachment->post_mime_type,0, 5)!="image")

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a variant of the page.php for that page and include something like the following in your loop:

```
<?php
   ob_start();
   the_content('Read the full post',true);
   $postOutput = preg_replace('/<img[^>]+./','', ob_get_contents());
   ob_end_clean();
   echo $postOutput;
?>
```